# create a table with multicolumns for comparison between 2 sources of data

Tags: tables

I wanted to create a table of three columns . the first has several rows and each of the second and third is divided into two columns. I do not know what could be wrong.

```
\document class{article}  
\newcommand{\splitcell}\[1\]{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\strut#1\strut\end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}\[htp\]
\centering

\caption{A caption}

\begin{tabular}{
    S\[table-format=2.0\] % Column 1
    S\[table-format=1.0\] % Column 2
    S\[table-format=1.6\] % Column 3
    S\[table-format=1.4\] % Column 4
    S\[table-format=1.3\] % Column 5
}

\toprule
{Metal type/ Metal thickness $t$(\si{\nano\meter})} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Akbari} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Naema} \\
\cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5}
 & & {$Re(n_{eff})$}  {\splitcell{\\$\alpha$\\(\si{dB/\mu m})}} &   {$Re(n_{eff})$}  {\splitcell{\\$\alpha$\\(\si{dB/\mu m})}}\\
\midrule
Al/100nm & 3.619 & 1.041 & 3.607517& 1.04979 \\
\midrule
Au/100nm & 3.772 & 1.228 &3.762532 & 1.29734 \\
\midrule
Al/20nm & 3.72 & 2 & 3.65266 & 2.00962\\
\midrule
Au/20nm & 4.2 & 5 & 4.001033 & 3.25059\\
\midrule
Al/10nm & 5.12 & 23.5 & 3.865893 & 5.12678\\
\midrule
Au/10nm &   NA & 33.5 & 4.809568 & 9.15694 \\

\bottomrule

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The table is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmnpX.png)

Comment: Well... first of all you need to understand more about [tables](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) and eventually learn more about `LaTeX`. Finally you'll need to write well your questions. You need to explain what's wrong, the bug or error when you compile or instead describe clearly what's your handicap or what you do not understand or don't know to get the expected result. I saw your picture and I don't find the complication of this table even if you do understand how to use multicolumn.

Comment: Can you please repost the latex. Currently it does not compile. Some of the issues are `\document class` (no space) and `[` and `]` both appear as `\[` and `\]`, respectively.  You are also missing some required packages and there are probably other problems. Please make sure that it compiles without errors.

Comment: Please read the link above in my first comment and analyse the answer of the question I answered yesterday. There is the solution to your question, you'll need to understand the multicolumn environment syntax.

Comment: @theEditors: Please do not edit the MWE of a question. This could hide the actual problems of the OP. Adressing the errors in comment (like above) or fixing the whole thing in an answer would be a better way. Thanks.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi - I've rolled back the two most recent rounds of revision, so that people can evaluate the original code more easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution, using `xcolor`, `colortbl`, `hhline` and `makecell`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[table, x11names, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\colorlet{myblue}{SteelBlue3}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator\re{\textsf{Re}}
\usepackage{array, hhline, caption}
\newcommand\myhline{\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{myblue}}->{\arrayrulecolor{Cornsilk1}}|----}}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\cellalign{lc}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\cellcolor{myblue}\color{Cornsilk1}\bfseries\boldmath}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
\def\nm{\si{\,\nm}}

\begin{document}
\rowcolors*{3}{SlateGray3!60}{Gainsboro!50}%[\cline{2-5}]
\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering
\sisetup{table-number-alignment=center,detect-all}
\caption{A caption}
\sffamily\arrayrulecolor{Cornsilk1}\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1.5pt}
\begin{tabular}%
   { >{\cellcolor{myblue}\color{Cornsilk1}\bfseries\boldmath}Cl |% Column 1
    S[table-format=1.2] |% Column 2
    S[table-format=2.3] |% Column 3
    S[table-format=1.6] |% Column 4
    S[table-format=1.5] % Column 5
}
\rowcolor{myblue}& \multicolumn{2}{>{\bfseries\color{Cornsilk1}}c}{Akbari} & \multicolumn{2}{>{\bfseries\color{Cornsilk1}}c}{Naema} \\
\myhline%
\rowcolor{myblue}\makecell{Metal type/Metal \\ thickness\enspace$t$(\si{\nano\meter})}& {\thead{$\re(n_{\mathbf{eff}})$}} & {\thead{$\alpha$\\(\si{dB/\micro\meter})}} & {\thead{$\re(n_{\mathrm{eff}})$}} & {\thead{$\alpha$\\(\si{dB/\micro\meter})}}\\
\myhline%
Al/100\nm & 3.619 & 1.041 & 3.607517& 1.04979 \\
Au/100\nm & 3.772 & 1.228 &3.762532 & 1.29734 \\
Al/20\nm & 3.72 & 2 & 3.65266 & 2.00962\\
Au/20\nm & 4.2 & 5 & 4.001033 & 3.25059\\
Al/10\nm & 5.12 & 23.5 & 3.865893 & 5.12678\\
Au/10\nm & {NA} & 33.5 & 4.809568 & 9.15694
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks Bernard, I really liked your way of coloring the table the way I want but unfortunately, I had problem separating the part of code that must be in the preamble from the part that must be with the table.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see what problem you have: the preamble part and the body part are already separated. Perhaps there are incompatibilities betwwen the rest of your preamble ang this code? Btw, note that your definition of `splitcell` is replaced with loading the `makecell` package, that has, among other features, the same functionality.

Answer (score 6):

Your code has quite a few problems, any one of which makes the MWE uncompilable. As far as I can tell, none of them are related to the fact you mention in the title of the posting, which is that the table groups two pairs of columns using `\multicolumn`.

- The first instruction should be `\documentclass`, not `\document class`
- The packages `siunitx` and `booktabs` need to be loaded
- When square brackets are called for, type `[` and `]`, *not* `\[` and `\]`. E.g., don't write `\begin{table}\[htp\]`; instead, write `\begin{table}[htp]`. Same goes for for the specification of the `S` columns.
- In the `\si` expressions, use `\micro\meter`, not `\mu m`
- Don't forget to insert `&` alignment dividers between some of the header cells. (The `tabular` environment has five columns, not three.)

Not outright errors, but important nonetheless:

- The first column can use type `c`; no need for anything more fancy
- When setting the value of `table-format`, strive to match the number of digits and decimals to the actual properties of the data inputs
- I suggest you add the `[t]` placement specifier to the `tabular` environment contained in the `splitcell` macro
- The very first `\\` line break instruction in both calls to `\splitcell` seems unnecessary.
- When you have an occasional non-numeric input, such as `NA`, in an `S` column type, be sure to center it by encasing it in curly braces. E.g., write `{NA}`, not just `NA`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\newcommand{\splitcell}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}\strut#1\strut\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\caption{A table}

\medskip
\begin{tabular}{
    c                   % Column 1
    S[table-format=1.3] % Column 2
    S[table-format=2.3] % Column 3
    S[table-format=1.6] % Column 4
    S[table-format=1.5] % Column 5
}

\toprule
Metal type\slash Metal thickness $t$ (\si{\nano\meter})
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Akbari} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Naema} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
 &  
{$Re(n_{\textit{eff}})$}  & 
{\splitcell{$\alpha$\\(\si{dB/\micro\meter})}} &   
{$Re(n_{\textit{eff}})$} & 
{\splitcell{$\alpha$\\(\si{dB/\micro\meter})}}\\
\midrule
Al/100nm & 3.619 & 1.041 & 3.607517& 1.04979 \\
\midrule
Au/100nm & 3.772 & 1.228 &3.762532 & 1.29734 \\
\midrule
Al/20nm & 3.72 & 2 & 3.65266 & 2.00962\\
\midrule
Au/20nm & 4.2 & 5 & 4.001033 & 3.25059\\
\midrule
Al/10nm & 5.12 & 23.5 & 3.865893 & 5.12678\\
\midrule
Au/10nm &   {NA} & 33.5 & 4.809568 & 9.15694 \\
\bottomrule

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot Mico, and thanks to everyone commented so far.